# почему в поле при отправке Ajax запроса все ведении данные сохраняется в поле воду?

Tags: ajax

почему в поле при отправке Ajax запроса все ведении данные сохраняется в поле воду.
например пользователю нужно вести в поле Name свое имя при натискани кнопки "отправить" будет срабатывать Ajax запрос. 
пользователь водит имя Андрей в поле и нажимает отправить но после отправки данных на сервер все же в поле остаются данные в нашем примере это имя Андрей. почему так? почему при нажатий отправить наше поле не обнуляется и сохраняет ранее введенные данные ???

Comment: А с чего вдруг поле само должно отчищаться? Делайте `reset()` формы.

Comment: Потому что вы его не очищаете.

Comment: @MedvedevDev да я знаю что нужно очистить input! меня интересует почему при отправке остаются данные в поле

Comment: @Bigdee да я знаю что нужно очистить input! меня интересует почему при отправке остаются данные в поле

Comment: @Kety Li, да, я понимаю, что вы ожидаете, что поле отчистится, но меня интересует: почему вы решили, что это должно происходить?

Comment: @MedvedevDev мне просто интересно почему остается данные!

Comment: @Kety Li, ну, потому что это ничем не обусловлено. Вы не перезагружаете страницу, не ресетаете форму ... ничто не говорит форме сбросить все значения при отправке, это не стандартное поведение при аяксе. Если хотите что бы сбросилось, то делайте ресет или перезагружайте страницу (но тогда не ясно зачем вообще делать аякс)